# What does dash "-" mean in Unix command line?

Tags: diff

Given this diff command:

> ./a.out < 1.in | diff - 1.out

What does `-` mean after the word diff?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: For `diff` in particular, [`-` is defined as standard input](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html#tag_20_34_05).

Comment: As the link mentions, many commands use `-` to mean either stdin or stdout, as appropriate. Eg, `wget -q -O- http://example.com` dumps the fetched HTML data to stdout (the `-q` is for **q**uiet mode so progress info isn't mixed with the HTML).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traditionally, *-* means stdin (standard input). As you're redirecting, the output of the first command is the input of the second.